# MiKTeX update fails due to missing mpm.exe

Tags: miktex, installing

I am running a freshly installed MiKTeX set-up (v2.9, x64) but it fails to install updates through the "Update" tool. After selecting packages to update, it downloads them but then interrupts the process with this error: `the MiKTeX package management utility could not be found`.

And when trying to open the Update tool from the "Package Manager" I immediately get this error: `The update helper could not be found`.

After some googling (see links below) I have come to believe that both problems are caused by the fact `mpm.exe` seems to be missing on my system.

Could anyone perhaps provide me with that missing exe? Preferably the x64 version.

**Edit** Possibly related bug reports I found:

- https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/mailman/miktex-users/thread/55885A07.4010207%40yahoo.de/#msg34230310
- https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/1920/

Comment: Opening the update manager from the package manager never really worked. Did you check with the package manager (admin) if there are new (miktex) packages (after doing repositories->synchronize) and did you install them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turned out the problem was indeed caused by the missing `mpm.exe`.

The reason is that somehow the (current) "Basic" MikTeX installer does not install the `miktex-mpmcli-bin` package. This *really* should be considered a bug because `mpm.exe` is essential for the correct working of a number of MikTeX (GUI) tools which said installer *does* install (e.g. the "Update" tool).

To resolve the problem it suffices to install the `miktex-mpmcli-bin` package through the "Package Manager".

Comment: Strange. I also installed  Basic MiKTeX (some years ago) and had no this problem.

Comment: If you think that there is a bug, than make a bug report.

Comment: Done: https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2387

Comment: Same problem today with a very old USB portable version of Miktex :)
Same solution, thanks a lot :)

Comment: problem is still here after a fresh install

Comment: package manager won't allow the miktex-mpmcli-bin package to be upgraded

Comment: I'm having the same problem as @hsmyers. When I go to "Packages" and search for `miktex-mpmcli-bin` I find the package `miktex-mpmcli-bin-2.9` but both "Install" and "Uninstall" options are grayed out. Anyone know how to get around this?